# How to identify the requested IP address distance in Java?

Tags: java, networking, ip

I would like to find the distance of IP address using Java. For example I have my server running in India and there are two requests to server, one is from US and another one is from Singapore. Now I would like to identify the shortest distance of requested IP. Is there a way I can achieve this efficiently?

Comment: "_Now I would like to identify the shortest distance of requested IP._" Which IP are you requesting, IPv4 or IPv6, and why do you think the distance would be different between the two different Internet Protocols? Most likely, requesting by both IPv4 and IPv6 is going to be the same distance.

Comment: It could be IPv4 or Ipv6. I am looking to identify the distance of requested terminal,so that I can forward the request to the closest server in a distributed environment

Answer (score 2):

Distance is not a good measure to identify the network-connectivity related issues.

Instead, you should consider the total number of hops made(or list of the routers traversed) before reaching the destination.

We have the [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) command for this :

> `traceroute` is a computer network diagnostic tool for displaying the
>   route (path) and measuring transit delays of packets across an
>   Internet Protocol (IP) network. The history of the route is recorded
>   as the round-trip times of the packets received from each successive
>   host (remote node) in the route (path); the sum of the mean times in
>   each hop is a measure of the total time spent to establish the
>   connection. Traceroute proceeds unless all (three) sent packets are
>   lost more than twice, then the connection is lost and the route cannot
>   be evaluated.

When run, `traceroute` outputs the list of traversed routers in a simple text format, together with timing information.

[image]

You can easily execute this command through ***java***, and parse the result to get the connectivity idea.

Comment: Quite often, transit providers cheat `traceroute`, in order to prevent their internal routing from being discovered. It is really only reliable on your own network. Also, the RFC for `traceroute` has been moved to historic status since it was not widely supported on the Internet; [RFC 6814.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6814) explains this.

Comment: @RonMaupin - I agree with you, but, at least, it would be the best criteria to be used for measuring, as it shows the time information too.